# macOS- The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store Xcode 8.1 / Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift3, database-migration

I'm diving back into the world of Cocoa and I'm having trouble when I make changes to my model with a new model version.

A few things.
1) I want to set-up a one-to-many relationship, this is the only change made in the v2 of the new model (error gets thrown when this is the selected version)

2) Both Entities were previously established in the first db

3) I think I need to perform a lightweight migration but thought this was supposed to be inferred.

4) I'm building for macOS

This is the error I'm getting thrown `The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`

Please let me know if I can provide more information

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight migration is only inferred if you tell Core Data to infer it.

If you're using `NSPersistentContainer` (new on the latest macOS), you'll find the options no the `NSPersistentStoreDescription` class. Set `shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically` and `shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically` to `true` and use the description object with the persistent container.

On older versions (or if you're just not using `NSPersistentContainer`), you'll include the migration options in the `options` parameter to `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.